# How can I cuta value by condition?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have next DataFrame:

```
link = [{'name': 'www.website.com/product-76tre53932'}, {'name': 'www.website.it/product-iee8340'}, {'name': 'www.website.de/product-ooi7309'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(link)
```

I think it can be cut -> 'product-'

I need the next result:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
df['name_2'] = df['name'].str.rsplit('-').str[-1]
```

This assumes you want everything after the last - character in each url.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use the split method in the following way -

```
link = [{'name': 'www.website.com/product-76tre53932'}, {'name': 'www.website.it/product-iee8340'}, {'name': 'www.website.de/product-ooienter code here7309'}]

for name in link:
    name['name'] = name['name'].split('product-')[1]
```

Now each name will remain with the value after the 'product-' as requested.